# Как изменять имена создающихся объектов

Tags: unity3d-android

В общем, у меня есть онлайн режим на фотоне, и там может быть 7 игроков максимум (в одной комнате) у них у всех одинаковое имя без цифр в конце, а мне надо чтобы в конце каждой машины до 7-ой были соотв. цифры (1 машина - *название машины*1, 2 машина - *название машины*2 и т.д), у всех машины абсолютно одинаковые названия, но этот скрипт присваивает цифру только первой машине, а остальные создаются с одинаковыми именами
этот скрипт создает машину :

```
private void Awake()
{
    // Создаем машину и добавляем номер в имя
    GameObject car = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(Player.name + carNumber, Spawns[Random.Range(0, Spawns.Length)].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

    // Вызываем метод, который присвоит нужный тег машине
    AllTheCarsController.AssignTagToCar(car.name, "Car" + carNumber);

    // Инкрементируем значение номера машины для следующей создаваемой машины
    carNumber++;
}
```

а этот пытается добавлять цифры к именам машин :

```
    // Получаем все машины в сцене с тегом "Car"
    GameObject[] allCars = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Car");

    // Ищем нужную машину по имени
    foreach (GameObject car in allCars)
    {
        if (car.name == carName)
        {
            // Нашли нужную машину, присваиваем ей тег
            car.tag = tag;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

заранее благодарен